# Error Intel Fortran calling C shared library function that receives an integer

Tags: c, linux, fortran, shared-libraries, intel-fortran

I am trying to run a C function from a Linux shared library (.so) from Fortran. The function in C receives an integer number from the Fortran program. I am not getting an erroneous value in C when using the intel compiler (2021.3.0), yet gfortran works without any issues. There seems to be a type error that I can't identify. I am creating an abstract interface following the syntax for interoperability established [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/mixed-language-programming/standard-fortran-and-c-interoperability.html)

Function in C:

```
int print_number(int n)
{
    printf("Hello world! %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}​
```

Function in Fortran

```
! Interface with shared library
abstract interface
    !% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    !% Simulation
    !% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    integer function print_number(number)
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        integer(c_int), value :: number
    end function print_number
end interface
```

The output when calling print_number(2):

Hello world! 734920112

I am attaching the files to reproduce the error [here](https://community.intel.com/cipcp26785/attachments/cipcp26785/fortran-compiler/158380/1/test.zip). First, execute `./compile.sh`, then `./run_test`

I would appreciate it a lot if someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Please do not upload a zip file to some third party site. Put the necessary [mcve] here as text right into your question. See [ask].

Comment: I will update the question and get rid of the external link to make the example and solution reproducible. I appreciate your recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use an *abstract* interface for this, but the problem probably comes from not using `bind(C)`.

Without `bind(C)` Intel Fortran compiles the function to expect a pointer (to a copy of something). To make it expect a value, use both `value` and `bind(C)`.

Comment: Thank you very much this solved the issue. You are right, if I don't use bind then the intel compiler treats every parameter as a pointer regardless of the value statement. When I defined the C function as: `int print_number(int * n)` the code worked. But will definitely adopt the bind statement to be able to pass parameters by value.